# Can't see the the "Watch" section in VS Code's debugging tab

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm talking about the "Watch" section described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection)

I tried to look for a way to set it on in the options and online but couldn't find out how.

Could it be that it specifically doesn't exist in the C# debugger? Maybe?

Comment: First try `View/Open View.../Watch` and see if it pops up.  Second, try the command `View: Reset View Locations`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up the settings file, uninstalling VS Code, rebooting my PC, and reinstalling VS Code.
Now the section is there. Which of these steps were necessary and which were not I can't tell, but it solved the problem.